# Is it Necessary to Check "n" returned by Write In Golang

Tags: networking, go

I have a server and start a goroutine for sending data. Code like this

```
func handleSend(conn *net.TcpConn, ch <-chan []byte) {
    for {
        select {
        case msg, ok := <-ch:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            n, err := conn.Write(msg)
            if err != nil {
                log.Error("conn write error", err)
                return
            }
            //here

        }
    }
}
```

Today, I think I should check `n` return by `conn.Write` to make sure that `msg` is writed completely.  So I add the following code in the place `here`

```
for ;n!= len(msg);{
     log.Error("conn write not completely", len(msg), "actually", n)
     msg = msg[n:]
     n, err = sess.conn.Write(msg)
     if err != nil {
         log.Error("conn write error", err)
         return
     }
 }
```

And I want to know is it right to do this?
PS  what if the peer receive message slowly and `Write` return with only part of the data sended successfully ?

Comment: You can check n when err != nil. Asume that you are writing 100 bytes, but while sending the connection is lost and it sends only a part of this 100 bytes, n stores the amount of bytes send. Is it useful to know the amount send? In most cases, no. But it is useful to store this in the log in case the receiver still want to work with the only partial received data and a new connection can not be made (never). You can also choose to ignore the n variable by replacing it with _ (underscore).

Answer (score 8):

[Docs say `Write` must return a non-nil error if it returns `n < len(p)`.](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) You may well find there's not much you can do with `n`, in which case you can assign it to `_`.